# I want to send image from a client to a server(using applets)

Tags: java, applet

I have signed my applet.I also have images in a file array.I just cannot figure out that how can I send these images to the server.any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please use HttpURLConnection class of java.net package to make communication from the server side scripting language